# How to assign a character value to all elements of a grouping variable

Tags: r

I have a very basic question:

I have a dataframe like so:

```
> head(xxx)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  perim                                   no
  <chr>                                   <chr>   
1 NA                                      9999-048
2 VALUE 1                                 9999-048
3 NA                                      9999-048
4 NA                                      9999-048
5 NA                                      9999-041
6 VALUE 2                                 9999-041
```

I have a grouping variable, `no` and I want to assign each element in `perim` with the corresponding value, with currently only one observation per `no`-group having a value.  My desired result would look like this:

```
 perim                                   no
  <chr>                                   <chr>   
1 VALUE 1                                9999-048
2 VALUE 1                                9999-048
3 VALUE 1                                9999-048
4 VALUE 1                                9999-048
5 VALUE 2                                9999-041
6 VALUE 2                                9999-041
```

I know there must be an easy way to go about this, but I seem to be stuck.
Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Use `na.locf` from `zoo` or `fill` from `tidyr`

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53210281/how-to-replace-nan-value-with-previous-non-nan-within-group/53210336#53210336

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, thanks. Just wanted to make sure OP looks  into the 'correct direction'.